# ValueError при работе с фиктивными переменными

Tags: python, pandas, искусственный-интеллект

Я делаю задание на построение модели линейной регрессии и тут возникает ошибка при присвоении переменной нового значения
Для начала мой датасет:

```
import pandas as pd
ind = [5375, 11681, 5325, 679, 12625, 8090, 11518, 16341, 2607,1742]
dats = {    'index' : [5376, 11682, 5326, 680, 12626, 8091, 11519, 16342, 2608,1743],
'date': [2011-8-16, 2012-5-6,2011-8-14,2011-1-31,2012-6-15,2011-12-8, 2011-4-30,2012-11-18, 
2011-4-23,2011-3-18],
'season': [4,3,4,2,3,1,3,1,3,2],
'yr': [0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0],
'mnth': [8,5,8,1,6,12,4,11,4,3],
'hr': [21,22,19,15,6,18,3,15,13,7],
'holiday': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
'weekday': [2,0,0,1,5,4,1,0,6,5],
'workingday': [1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1],
'weathersit': [1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1],
'temp':[0.72,0.56,0.72,0.16,0.54,0.28,0.40,0.42,0.52,0.4],
'atemp': [0.6667, 0.5303, 0.6970, 0.1818, 0.5152, 0.2727, 0.4091, 0.4242, 0.5000, 0.4091],
'hum':[0.54, 0.73, 0.74, 0.59, 0.83, 0.52, 0.76, 0.54, 0.83, 0.66],
'windspeed': [0.0000, 0.1642, 0.2239, 0.1343, 0.1343, 0.2239, 0.1642, 0.2836, 0.3881, 0.1940],
'cnt': [215, 157, 259, 44, 151, 318, 4, 407, 312, 123]}
 data = pd.DataFrame(data=dats, index=ind)
```

Задания:

1. Для дальнейшей работы с моделями для каждой категориальной переменной мы создадим фиктивные переменные во избежание неправильного порядка категорий

   ```
    def get_dummies(df: pd.DataFrame):
      features = pd.concat([df,
                  pd.get_dummies(df[['season', 'yr','mnth', 'hr','holiday','weekday', 'workingday', 'weathersit']]),
                  ], axis = 1
                 )
      features = features.drop(['season',
                        'mnth', 
                        'weekday', 
                        'weathersit'
                        ], axis = 1)
      return features




    features = get_dummies(data)

    2. На основе переменной времени создайте новую переменную, которая будет отвечать за день и ночь.

   features['night_hours'] = features['hr']
   features = features.drop('hr', axis = 1)
   ```

Выскакивает ошибка

```
KeyError: 'night_hours'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
KeyError: 'night_hours'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in check_ndim(values, 
placement, ndim)
1978         if len(placement) != len(values):
1979             raise ValueError(
-> 1980                 f"Wrong number of items passed {len(values)}, "
1981                 f"placement implies {len(placement)}"
1982             )

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

Comment: а где вы эти `night_hours` определяете? `features['night_hours'] ` как из ниоткуда появляется.

Comment: оно там было оставлено